# How to correct the spelling of app name in App Store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I know this may be impossible but...

I just got an app approved, and everywhere (that I can see) it is capitalized correctly - it's called "Daybreak", but when you download it, the name under the icon is "daybreak".  I let Xcode take care of all that naming stuff this time, so I'm not sure where it got changed, or where the app store is taking the app name from.  Like I said, every where else it is correct - just not under the icon in my phone!

[EDIT] One other place it shows up lower case is in the organizer for its archive.  On the left it's lower case; when selected, it's lower case in the large font at the top of the details, and upper case just below that...

[EDIT] I should mention that I'm using Xcode 4...

[EDIT] The following are from my target's info tab:

```
Bundle display name   ${PRODUCT_NAME}
Bundle identifier     com.lollygaggersoft.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}
```

[EDIT] I was able to fix the issue by manually changing my Bundle display name to the correct capitalization and leaving the Bundle identifier alone.  This worked when I submitted my update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at Info tab in Target settings. There are two keys:

**Bunle name** -- is name of directory (followed by .app) where all program stuff are kept.

**Bundle display name** -- is wat you exactly need, it is the name that will be displayed in SpringBoard

It's common to set both bundle name and bundle display name to ${PRODUCT_NAME}, than set field **"Product name"** in project Build settings to whatever you want

PS In organizer you see bundle name in small fond and bundle display name in large font.

PPS AFAIK you need to upload another version to appstore in order to change display name.

Comment: I've updated my question with what's in those two fields - they reference something else, but I don't know where to look for them.

Comment: @Steve **bundle display name** seems to be correct, now check **Product name** in project Build Settings. Also check in Target Build Settings

Comment: `Product name` was set to "daybreak" - that was it!  Now when I archive, it is correct.  Thank you!  We'll see if I can update it in the store now...

Comment: @Steve only by uploading new version, don't forget to change minor version in Summary, i.e. if version of your app was 1.0 change to something like 1.0.1. Otherwise Application Loader will reject your app